# CodeIgniter 3 MySQL - verifying users password is not working

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

The following function is not returning true and I do not understand why. I'm not getting any database errors, but it definitely returns false for some reason. The table and field names are 100% correct.

```
public function verify_password($username, $password){
    $this->db->select('password');
    $this->db->from('user_account');
    $this->db->where('username', $username);
    $query = $this->db->get();

    if($query == $password){
      return true;
    } else {
      return false;
    }
  }
```

Comment: if($query->row(0) == $password)

Comment: Don't store plain text passwords. Instead use [`password_hash()`](http://us3.php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php) and [`password_verify()`](http://us3.php.net/manual/en/function.password-verify.php).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that you need to get some results from your query. Read about [Generating Query Results](https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/results.html).

Revised method as follows

```
public function verify_password($username, $password)
{
    //use method chaining, it's more efficient and less typing
    $query = $this->db
        ->select('password')
        ->from('user_account')
        ->where('username', $username)
        ->get();

    //were any matching rows found?
    if($query->num_rows() > 0)
    {
        // get first row of data and check 'password' value against passed value
        // return is a boolean
        return $query->row()->password === $password;
    }

    //There are no rows that match so clearly not logged in
    return false;
}
```

As the comments in your question point out you should not store plain text passwords.

Comment: I think he is storing plain passwords.

Comment: It was the way that I was trying to access the query result to compare with the password that was the issue. And yes I understand they should not be stored as plaintext, I will get round to that eventually. Thanks!